# nginx try_files and react-router always serves index page

Tags: nginx, react-router

I have a node.js application running in tandem with a Spring Boot backend application that I am proxying through nginx 1.10.1.  My config file looks like this:

```
worker_processes 1;
error_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  # Note this log_format is named 'main', and is used with the access log below
  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;

  upstream appservice {
    server localhost:9084;
  }

  upstream appui {
  server localhost:3000;
  }

  proxy_buffer_size   128k;
  proxy_buffers   4 256k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name localhost;
      access_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/my_site.local.access.log  main;
      error_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/my_site.local.error.log error;

      location / {
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_pass         http://appui;
          try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      }

      location /services {
      rewrite ^/services(.*) /$1 break;
          proxy_pass         http://appservice;
      }
  }
}
```

In this configuration, EVERYTHING gets sent to index.html, even for subpaths that exist (i.e, `/bundle.js`).  If I take out `try_files`, then the page serves up as normal, but react-router no longer works because requests aren't routed to that page.

Any ideas on how I fix this?

EDIT:  I seem to have found a way to get what I asked for, but not what I want.

If I structure the nginx configuration file this way, then it loads the bundle and the index page properly.  Now the problem is that pages show up as blank; the script doesn't execute, and the `/` route always shows the nginx welcome page:

```
server {
      listen 80;
      server_name localhost;
      access_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/my_site.local.access.log  main;
      error_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/my_site.local.error.log error;

      try_files $uri $uri/  @proxy;

      location @proxy {
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_pass         http://vpagerui;
      }

      location /services {
          rewrite ^/services(.*) /$1 break;
          proxy_pass         http://vpagerservice;
      }   
  }
```

Here is how I have react-router configured:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, Link, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import Welcome from './welcome';
import Merchant from './merchant';
import CreateMerchant from './create-merchant';
import TakeTicket from './take-ticket';
import TicketStatus from './ticket-status';
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
// /* globals document, window */
//
// const { pathname, search, hash } = window.location
// const location = `${pathname}${search}${hash}`

render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Welcome}/>
        <Route path="/merchant" component={CreateMerchant}/>
        <Route path="/merchant/:merchantId" component={Merchant}/>
        <Route path="/merchant/:merchantId/tickets/take-ticket" component={TakeTicket} />
        <Route path="/merchant/:merchantId/tickets/:ticketId" component={TicketStatus} />
    </Router>
), document.getElementById("app"))
```

What can I do to get pages to load properly and execute the `bundle.js` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I was able to get close enough to an answer to be workable.  It still doesn't work for the `/` path, but I added a `/home` route, which will work well enough for me.

nginx.conf:

```
# Replace /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf with this. This is the
# default location for Nginx according to 'nginx -h'
worker_processes 1;
error_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log;

events {
  worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  # This should be in the same directory as this conf
  # e.g. /usr/local/etc/nginx
  include       mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;

  # Note this log_format is named 'main', and is used with the access log below
  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
    '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  sendfile        on;
  keepalive_timeout  65;

  upstream areasetservice {
    server localhost:9084;
  }

  upstream areasetui {
  server localhost:3000;
  }

  # Without this I got this error: 'upstream sent too big header
  # while reading response header from upstream'
  proxy_buffer_size   128k;
  proxy_buffers   4 256k;
  proxy_busy_buffers_size   256k;

  server {
      listen 80;
      server_name localhost;
      access_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/my_site.local.access.log  main;
      error_log /usr/local/var/log/nginx/my_site.local.error.log error;


      location / {
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_pass         http://areasetui;
          index /index.html;
      }

      location /services {
      rewrite ^/services(.*) /$1 break;
          proxy_pass         http://areasetservice;
      }
  }
}
```

The React router...

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Router, Route, Link, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import Welcome from './welcome';
import Area from './Area';
import CreateArea from './create-area';
import Takemap from './take-map';
import MyMapStatus from './map-status';
require('bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css');
// /* globals document, window */
//
// const { pathname, search, hash } = window.location
// const location = `${pathname}${search}${hash}`

render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Welcome}/>
        <Route path="/home" component={Welcome} />
        <Route path="/Area" component={CreateArea}/>
        <Route path="/Area/:AreaId" component={Area}/>
        <Route path="/Area/:AreaId/maps/take-map" component={TakeMyMap} />
        <Route path="/Area/:AreaId/maps/:mapId" component={MyMapStatus} />
    </Router>
), document.getElementById("app"))
```